# Não consigo inserir usuário através do banco de dados/php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, inserir

Bom dia, pessoal.
Estou enfrentando um problema um tanto quanto constrangedor.
Consigo fazer a atualização de usuário através do painel que eu construí, porém não consigo adicionar um usuário novo na mesma.

Segue o código.

```html
<?   
  if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
   $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
   $nome   = $_POST['nome'];
   $senha  = md5($_POST['senha']);
   $email   = $_POST['email'];
   $nivel   = $_POST['nivel'];
   $funcao  = $_POST['funcao'];
   $menus  = implode(",", $_POST['menus']);
   $acesso  = $_POST['acesso'];

   $sql = "
    INSERT INTO tbl_usuarios(
     nome_usuario, 
     login_usuario, 
     senha_usuario,
     email_usuario, 
     nivel_usuario,
     funcao_usuario,
     menus_usuario,
     acesso_usuario,
    ) 
    VALUES(
     '".$nome."',
     '".$matricula."',     
     '".$senha."',
     '".$email."',
     '".$nivel."',
     '".$funcao."',
     '".$menus."',
     '".$acesso."',
    )"; 
   $sucesso = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
   $id = mysql_insert_id();

   if ($sucesso){
    echo "<p class='sucesso'>Dados inseridos corretamente - CÓDIGO USUÁRIO: ".$id."</p>";
   }else 
    die(mysql_error());
  } 
 ?>
 <br /> 
<form id="frmUsuarios" name="frmUsuarios" action='#' method='POST'>
<table border="0" id="tabela_incluir">
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">Matrícula*:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="6" id="matricula" name="matricula" class="input validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]]" onblur="validaUser()" maxlength="6" />&nbsp;<span id="valid"></span>
        </td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">Nome*:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="66" name="nome" class="input validate[required]" /></td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">Senha*:</td>
        <td><input type="password" size="40" name="senha" class="input-normal validate[required]" /></td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">E-mail*:</td>
        <td><input type="email" size="40" name="email" class="input-normal validate[required,custom[email]]" /></td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">Nível*:</td>
        <td><select name="nivel" class="select validate[required]">
      <?
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
    FROM tbl_nivel_acesso 
    ORDER BY 3"
   );
   print ("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
   while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print("<option value='{$rows['niv_nivel']}'");
     print(">$rows[niv_descricao_nivel]");
    print("</option>");
   }
   ?>
   </select></td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">Função*:</td>
        <td><select name="funcao" class="select validate[required]">
      <?
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
    FROM tbl_funcao 
    ORDER BY 2"
   );
   print ("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
   while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print("<option value='{$rows['id_funcao']}'");
     print(">$rows[descricao_funcao]");
    print("</option>");
   }
   ?>
   </select></td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">Menus*:</td>
        <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="1" class="validate[required]" /> Cadastros
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="2" class="validate[required]" /> Clientes
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="3" class="validate[required]" /> Projetos
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="4" class="validate[required]" /> Logs
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="5" class="validate[required]" /> Boletos
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="6" class="validate[required]" /> Pagamentos
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="7" class="validate[required]" /> Contas
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="8" class="validate[required]" /> Contato
        </td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
     <td class="dir">Acesso*:</td>
        <td>
         <select name="acesso" class="select validate[required]">
             <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1">SIM</option>
                <option value="0">NÃO</option>
            </select>
        </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
        <td align="right">
   <input type="button" class="button" value="Gravar" />
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Voltar" name="voltar" onclick="location.href='?acessando=usuarios-listar&titulo=USUÁRIOS';">
            <input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' />
  </td>
 </tr> 
</table>
</form>
```

O código funciona perfeitamente se eu quiser editar o nível do usuário, a função, porém se eu vou criar o cadastro de um, e clico em "gravar", ele não faz nada, não insere o usuário dentro da database com as informações, e nem ao mesmo mostra uma mensagem de erro.
Alguém poderia verificar pra mim se o mesmo contém algum erro?

Comment: Sem erro fica mais difícil. Mas olhando seu código, se o mesmo script funciona para `update`, mas não para `insert`, será que seu usuário do BD está sem privilégio para inserir dados?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
$acao = mysql_escape_string($_GET['matricular']);

if($acao == 'sim'):
            $matricula  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['matricula'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $nome       = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nome'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $senha      = md5($_POST['senha']);
            $email      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $nivel      = $_POST['nivel'];
            $funcao     = $_POST['funcao'];
            $menus      = implode(",", $_POST['menus']);
            $acesso     = $_POST['acesso'];

            $sql = mysql_query("
                INSERT INTO tbl_usuarios(nome_usuario, login_usuario, senha_usuario,email_usuario, nivel_usuario,funcao_usuario,menus_usuario,acesso_usuario) VALUES('$nome','$matricula','$senha','$email','$nivel','$funcao','$menus','$acesso')"); 

            if ($sucesso){
                echo "<p class='sucesso'>Dados inseridos corretamente - CÓDIGO USUÁRIO: ".$id."</p>";
            }else {
                echo ('Ops.. Ocorreu um erro... Informe o suporte.');
            }

    endif;
    ?>
    <br />  
<form id="frmUsuarios" name="frmUsuarios" action='?matricular=sim' method='POST'>
<table border="0" id="tabela_incluir">
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">Matrícula*:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="6" id="matricula" name="matricula" class="input validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]]" onblur="validaUser()" maxlength="6" />&nbsp;<span id="valid"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">Nome*:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="66" name="nome" class="input validate[required]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">Senha*:</td>
        <td><input type="password" size="40" name="senha" class="input-normal validate[required]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">E-mail*:</td>
        <td><input type="email" size="40" name="email" class="input-normal validate[required,custom[email]]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">Nível*:</td>
        <td><select name="nivel" class="select validate[required]">
            <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                FROM tbl_nivel_acesso 
                ORDER BY 3"
            );
            print ("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                print("<option value='{$rows['niv_nivel']}'");
                    print(">$rows[niv_descricao_nivel]");
                print("</option>");
            }
            ?>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">Função*:</td>
        <td><select name="funcao" class="select validate[required]">
            <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                FROM tbl_funcao 
                ORDER BY 2"
            );
            print ("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                print("<option value='{$rows['id_funcao']}'");
                    print(">$rows[descricao_funcao]");
                print("</option>");
            }
            ?>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">Menus*:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="1" class="validate[required]" /> Cadastros
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="2" class="validate[required]" /> Clientes
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="3" class="validate[required]" /> Projetos
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="4" class="validate[required]" /> Logs
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="5" class="validate[required]" /> Boletos
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="6" class="validate[required]" /> Pagamentos
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="7" class="validate[required]" /> Contas
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="8" class="validate[required]" /> Contato
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cor2">
        <td class="dir">Acesso*:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="acesso" class="select validate[required]">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1">SIM</option>
                <option value="0">NÃO</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Gravar" />
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Voltar" name="voltar" onclick="location.href='?acessando=usuarios-listar&titulo=USUÁRIOS';">
            <input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' />
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Tome cuidados pois o <? não está mais sendo usado procure mudar para <?php  Copie o codigo e teste esse provavelmente está certo

Comment: Testei e a mesma coisa. Vi que você botou um código para caso ocorra algum erro. Mesmo com isso, ele não me retorna o erro que você adicionou e não adiciona dentro do banco de dados. Mais alguma sugestão?

Comment: veja sua conecção ou a configuração da sua db pois o codigo está certo ao meu ver. Hey eu n editei só o php editei o formulario tmb.!